# few questions on morphium

Tags: java, mongodb, orm

I'm new to morphium, have gone thru docs and tests and have few questions on it.

1: Is *Morphium* object thread-safe and can we keep a static reference (only create one time) to it and use in all threads? If yes, anything to take care? Else should we keep a static reference to *MorphimConfig* object, and create *Morphium* object from it everytime its needed?

2. Does creating Morphium object also creates a new connection to mongo DB?  Will it automatically close/release the connection once its GC'd?
3. Next question is regarding lifecycle callback methods, i.e. prestore, poststore etc. These are supposed to go in the entity class with appropriate annotations. Is it possible to define them elsewhere in order to keep my entity classes least polluted and dependent on morphium? I.e. it might be easy to switch to another provider later if only annotations are left in pojos.
4. Many of my pojos have long id field (I'll not have too many docs in each collection, so it should not be a problem), and tried to use SequenceGenerator with PreStore(). SeqGen requires a morphium instance, and it means I need to create one more morphium object into PreStore(), even though one morphium is already processing the entity. Is it not possible to get the handle to the same morphium instance that triggered the callback? Or the morphium instance etc is passed into the callbacks?
5. Or preferably, I suggest to provide one more annotation like 'AutoIncrement', and when its placed on a Long type ID field and no value is in field, morphium can internally use SeqGen to put appropriate value into the field, and return new value/entity. That'd make it totally transparent.

I also wanted to tag it with '**morphium**' but can't create a new tag. If somebody can please create and tag the question, it'll be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Whoever marked it negative: Do you care to give a reason as well?

Answer (score 0):

Here some answers:

1. Morphium is 100% thread safe. We used it in several project as singleton. Even the built in cache in Morphium is threadsafe. 
   Morphium itself keeps a reference to the config object.
2. Morphium uses a connection pool (depending on configuration and the driver used). When calling close on the Morphium Object, it will close all connections and shut down the pools (also threadpools used). If you forget to close, there is a shutdown hook, taking care when exiting.
3. Well yes and no. The callback classes themselves are only available in the entity classes. This is intended for pre calculating values or something.

If you want to centralize things, you can also register several listeners (StorageListener etc). These can be registered by type or globally.

4. Not sure if I understand correctly. If you define your ID field as MorphiumID it will be generated for you. If you need a long as if, you can use the sequence generators. These are threadsafe and you could use them as singleton. If you have more than one Morphium object, that would also work as sequences are synchronized via mongo. (There is a kind of locking, monitor algorithm going on which assures that even several clients or Morphiums  will get proper numbers.)
5. Is possible to implement but I cannot see the difference in using Morphium IDs. which will be translated internally to ObjectIds and can be converted to and from Longs.

Hope that helps.